# Using a for loop in Microsoft cmd.exe, how can I process only the files with a certain extension?

Tags: windows, windows-7, batch-file, batch, windows-command-prompt

I have a the folder `c:\test\` and two files in it `a.txt` and `b.txtv`.

I would like to process just the files with extension equal to `.txt`.

If I write this commands

```
cd c:\test
for %f in (*.txt) do echo %f
```

I will get the result where both `a.txt` and `b.txtv` are listed.

The same happens with

```
cd c:\test
dir *.txt
```

It seems `.txt` is the same of `.txtv`.

I have Windows XP SP3 in Italian and the result of

```
ver
```

is `Microsoft Windows XP [Versione 5.1.2600]`.

The same result is from Windows 7 in English `Microsoft Windows XP [Version 6.1.7601]`.

Comment: Just a side note but Windows Ver. 6.1 is the official version number for Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for %%I in (*.*) do if "%%~xI"==".txt" (echo %%I)
```

That should do it.

Edit: that's the "scripting" syntax. If you want to type this at the command line, you must remove one of the % sign each time they are doubled, linke this:

```
for %I in (*.*) do if "%~xI"==".txt" (echo %I)
```

Answer (score 7):

Try using `forfiles` instead.  It seems to be more restrictive on what it returns for the extension, plus it has the added benefit of a built in `for` loop.  Should already be on the Win7 box, but you might have to install a 2003 Server Resource kit on the XP box to get it on there.

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple in PowerShell and works fine with the following:

```
PS C:\Users\bpabst\Desktop> ls *.txt


Directory: C:\Users\bpabst\Desktop


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---          7/2/2012  11:19 AM         11 test.txt
```

Comment: So how does this explain the behavior OP is seeing with `cmd` and `FOR`?

Comment: How about in this pre-existing question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523043/how-to-loop-through-files-and-rename-using-powershell

Comment: I'm still not seeing "powershell" listed anywhere in the OP's question. They even tagged it [batch] and [cmd].

Comment: "Better technology" -- Sorry, I think you're missing the point of the OP's question.